# When I fork a collection in Postman, I can't change the example returned by my mock server

Tags: postman

I have a collection with API tests that I work on with a colleague. Therefore, we use Postman versioning and make our changes in forks.
After writing tests, I like to make sure they fail when they're supposed to, so I use a mock server.

Now, when I am in a fork and I change an example that the mock server returns, I still get  the unchanged example (and yes, I saved it).
Only when I merge the fork back into the main collection, I can change the example and verify that my test fails when it should.

On the other hand, when I have 2 examples to a request in my main collection, I can delete one in the fork, still leaving 2 examples in the main collection. Therefore, it seems that the examples in the main collection and the fork are independent.

Is that a bug or did I miss something. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking a collection doesn't fork the mock server also , so the example is not connected to the mock server. You have to create a separate mock for your fork